# StringScanner and scan_until

Tags: ruby

Here's a simple example:

```
string = "aaa <x> bbb ccc <x> ddd <x>"
ss = StringScanner.new(string)
```

I'm interested in scanning for instances of `<x>` and everything else (whatever that might be). I can't really use `scan` because I have no idea about the format of text other than `<x>` (nor do I care).

```
ss.scan_until(/<x>/)
=> "aaa <x>"
ss[0]
=> "<x>"
```

So `ss[0]` gives me what my regex matched. How do I get rest of the text? `pre_match` grabs everything back to the start of the original string and not back to the previous pointer. As a work-around I just do `result.sub(ss[0], '')` to get my text. Seems clunky and almost like I'm not using some method I missed.

To clarify, I want this output:

```
["aaa ", "<x>"," bbb ccc ", "<x>", " ddd ", "<x>"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `split` to get the rest:

```
string.split(/<x>/)
#=> ["aaa ", " bbb ccc ", " ddd "]
```

Edit: To preserve order including the delimiter, as Cary points out, just include the delimiter in the split via a capture group:

```
string.split(/(<x>)/)
#=> ["aaa ", "<x>", " bbb ccc ", "<x>", " ddd ", "<x>"]
```

Comment: I want to preserve order, so that's not it. There's also `String.scan` btw, but constructing and running regex to get touples of out string is complicated and slow.

Comment: Grocery, is `string.split(/(<x>)/) #=> ["aaa ", "<x>", " bbb ccc ", "<x>", " ddd ", "<x>"]` what you want? (I just put `<x>` in a capture group to return the splitters as well as the splitees.) If you don't want the leading and trailing spaces in the strings returned in the array, `string.split(/\s*\K(<x>)\s*/) #=> ["aaa", "<x>", "bbb ccc", "<x>", "ddd", "<x>"]`. In this regex, `\K` means "forget everything matched so far". It's need because Ruby doesn't support variable-length positive lookbehinds.

Comment: split with capture group is perfect. didn't know it did that. thanks.